# Laravel and Redis - Store Caching data

Tags: php, laravel, caching, redis, multiple-domains

Actually, I have 4 websites, now on redis I want to store caching of all the four domain and store them separately.
I want that cache is stored separately for the individual domains, so that when I clear cache for a
domain, it only clears cache for this one domain, instead of clearing the entire Redis cache for all domains.

Can anyone help me on this where We can implement above scenario using Laravel and Redis?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do multiple redis servers. They should probably be separate anyway for security purposes.

Comment: @JohnV. and for scalability. if one site receives more traffic and has more pages - you will bust your cache if everything is in one basket and gets too full.